# How to use List <> with WebElement in selenide?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenide

I use selenide in my tests. There are selenideElement collections in selenide.
I would like to replace it with List .
**The code in selenide looks like this:**

```
ElementsCollection trElements = $$ ("tr");
```

**To Selenium:**

```
List <WebElement> trElements = $$ ("tr");
```

**But an error occurs:**
"incompatible types: com.codeborne.selenide.ElementsCollection cannot be converted to java.util.List "

**How to convert ElementCollection to List correctly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In selenide, search through webElements is done like this:

```
  List<WebElement> table = WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().findElements("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly you need to convert collection to list:

```
List<WebElement> trElements = new List<WebElement>($$ ("tr"));
```

There are more ways how to convert it. See https://www.baeldung.com/java-convert-collection-arraylist

Comment: `new List<WebElement>($$ ("tr"));` >>> `new ArrayList<>($$ ("tr"));`